# UseExceptionHandler Blazor server-side not working

Tags: blazor

I’m new at Blazor development and I have the problem that I’m not able to test or to make the Error Page to show up when I add an exception.
Here what I have done so far:

Here what I have done so far:
I created a new Blazor Server Project out of VS2022, select Framework .Net 6.0, without authentication. This creates the standard template project.

```
Commented out the if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) line
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
//{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
//}
```

Added a throw new Exception after counter increment:

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        throw new Exception("This is my Exception !!");
    }
}
```

Started application out of VS2022.
And now I expect that if a Click on the “Click me” button, the error page defined under Error.cshtml should be displayed.
But I get only “An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details. Reload» at the end of my page and I have to press on reload in the browser.
I know about the ErrorBoundary component.
In my opinion as I understand the use of UseExceptionHandler(“/Error”)  this should handle all possible Exceptions and show the Error page without using ErrorBoundary component.
What is my mistake or where did I misunderstand something?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my opinion as I understand the use of UseExceptionHandler(“/Error”) this should handle all possible Exceptions and show the Error page without using ErrorBoundary component.

No, `UseExceptionHandler(“/Error”)` can't show the error message. Indeed, lots of ASP Core middleware scenarios will not work completely in a server-side Blazor application in all running phases. This is because Blazor works with `SignalR` and the Blazor Hub.

When starting a Blazor application, there are first a few HTTP requests that will pass the pipeline till the end. (in most cases these are the initial page load and then a negotiation phase). So in this phase if an exception occurs then the application use the `app.UseExceptionHandler` and the `Error.cshtml` to show the error, However, then comes a request to "/_blazor" and this is the moment that the connection stays open to continue communication through websockets. If you have an exception after this phase, it will not enter your exception handler. So you have to catch the exception manually with try catch block in the components or use the `<ErrorBoundary>`.

So you should put the `<ErrorBoundary>` in the component. As you know, The `<ErrorBoundary>` is a predefined Blazor component that has an easy approach to error display as follows:

- When no error has occurred, it renders its child content.
- When an unhandled exception occurs, it renders the default error page.

So for example, to globally define Error boundary, it can be defined as follows in `Shared/MainLayout.razor` file:

```
 <div>
    <div>
        <ErrorBoundary>
            @Body
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, any uncontrolled exception that occurs in the entire components is controlled by UseExceptionHandler and then set Error boundaries to show an error on the page. By default, the Error boundary component shows an empty div with a CSS class in site.css called `blazor-error-boundary` as the error page, which can be customized. You can also do the following to further customize the error page:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        @Body
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent>
        <p class="errorUI">Sorry, It's an error.</p>
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

If you'd like the page to return to the state before the exception without the need for the user to refresh the page, then you can define the `recover` method as follows:

```
...

<ErrorBoundary @ref="errorBoundary">
    @Body
</ErrorBoundary>

...

@code {
    private ErrorBoundary? errorBoundary;

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        errorBoundary?.Recover();
    }
}
```

You can also create a custom middleware, for more info you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61581745/4444757).

Comment: First of all, thanks AlirezaK for your explanation. 
So, if I understand you, ErrorBoundary catches all possible Exceptions in my Blazor Server app? I don’t have to care more about unhandled exceptions?
Do I still need to call app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); in my Program.cs?
and what’s the reason for the generated Error.cshtml file? This is never used or am I wrong?
Why does VS2022 generate this code, if it doesn’t work under Blazor Server?

Comment: `Do I still need to call app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); in my Program.cs?...` Yes, because when starting a Blazor application, there are first a few HTTP requests that will pass the pipeline till the end. (in most cases these are the initial page load and then a negotiation phase). So in this phase if an exception occurs then the application use the `app.UseExceptionHandler` and the `Error.cshtml` to show the error.

Comment: However, then comes a request to "/_blazor" and this is the moment that the connection stays open to continue communication through websockets. If you have an exception after this phase, it will not enter your exception handler. So you have to catch the exception manually with try catch block in the components and other services.

Comment: I have also updated my answer to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: `ErrorBoundary catches all possible Exceptions in my Blazor Server app?` the `ErrorBoundary` will render error UI when unhandled exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlirezaK. Do you know a good website link where all this behaviour of Blazor server is explained in deep? Maybe that would help me to more understand what happens in more details.
Once more, thanks a lot for your time helping me to understand these thinks.

Comment: ` I don’t have to care more about unhandled exceptions?`  You should manage the exception in other layers of your app yourself, such as services layer and so on.

Comment: Because the blazor is an emerging technology, there is no in-depth and comprehensive documentation in the way you are looking for. In order to be able to answer your questions more precisely, I had to do a lot of research and edit my answer many times. However, for example it's a good link that describe error boundary https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/11/dotnet6-feature-blazor-app-handling-errors-using-error-boundaries-component.html